# Modify list of users in drop down list data bind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the code below to display a list of users in a drop down box. If a user is locked out or disabled, how would I go about adding this to the list also?

So for example, if we have the name 'John' in the list ... If the account were disabled how could it be changed so that it displays 'John - Disabled' in the list?

**EDIT**: After adding a for each loop, if only one account is disabled, the entire list says disabled - not just for that one account.

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private webUsers As MembershipUserCollection

Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete

    webUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers()

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        UserName.DataSource = webUsers
        UserName.DataBind()

    End If

     For Each item As Object In UserName.Items
        If item Is IsApproved = False Then
            item.text = item.ToString & " - Disabled"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Did your edit pretty much answer your own question?

Comment: It has gotten me closer to my answer, I can't seem to find a way to alter that users value within the drop down list.

Comment: Your `For Each` loop is probably broken because of this:  `If item Is IsApproved = False Then`.  `Is` is for checking the Type of an object, not a property value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you just need to use the correct `type` rather than `Object`, so the `GetAllUsers()` return a `MemeberUserCollection`, so rather than an `Object` use a `MembershipUser`

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private webUsers As MembershipUserCollection

Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete

    webUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers()

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        UserName.DataSource = webUsers
        UserName.DataBind()

    End If

     ' Option One - Loop through the webusers collection

     For Each item As MembershipUser In webUsers
        If item.IsApproved = False Then
             UserName.Items.FindByValue(item.UserName).Text += " - Disabled" 
        End If
    Next

    ' Option two - Loop through the ListItems of the list box
     For Each item As ListItem In UserName.Items
        If Membership.GetUser(item.Text).IsApproved = False Then
             item.Text += " - Disabled" 
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is modify the underlying object in the `webUsers` collection.  Make a new `ReadOnly Property` that performs the dynamic logic and use that new property as the `DisplayText` for the dropdown list control.

<strike>Without seeing more information on the definition of the `webUsers` collection, it's hard to give a concrete example.</strike>

```
Public Class WebUser
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property UserId As Integer
    Public Property IsApproved As Boolean

    Public ReadOnly Property DisplayName As String
        Get
            If Not IsApproved Then Return String.Format("{0} - Disabled", Name)
            Return Name
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Could you go into a little detail about how this can be accomplished?

Comment: @user2867494 I've just added a basic concrete example of the WebUser class.  YMMV

Answer (score 0):

try this...
            item.text = item.ToString() + "- Disabled"